# Adding floating numbers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to add all the BMI results together and then display it, keep getting a error :

`TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`

Also keep getting None printed when i run my program after a bmi is calculated>?

```
def bmirange():
if bmi >= 25.0:
    print('Your BMI measurement shows that you are overweight')
elif bmi <18.0:
        print('Your BMI measurement shows that you are underweight')
else:
        print('Your BMI measurement shows that you are in the healty weight band')




weight = float(input('What is your weight in Kg? '))
height = float(input('What is your height in Meters? '))
bmi = weight / (height * height)
print(bmi)
print(bmirange())

bmiredo = input('Do you want to do another BMI measurement?, y / n ')

while bmiredo == 'y':
weight = float(input('What is your weight in Kg? '))
height = float(input('What is your height in Meters? '))
print(bmi)
print(bmirange())
bmiredo = input('Do you want to do anoher BMI measurement?, y / n ')
else:
print('ok, the total of your BMI results are')

print(sum(bmi))

input('press the enter key to exit')
```

Comment: why you taking weight in `int` take that too in float

Comment: please provide code we can test.

Comment: you are getting None because you don't have a return value, python return None by default if you don't have a return statement in yout function

Comment: @hennessyd, did you edit and remove the `print(sum(bmi))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
print(sum(bmi))
```

The `bmi` variable is a number, but if you want to use `sum()` you need a list of numbers.  Here is how you can collect a list of numbers.  The `.append()` method adds an element to the end of a list.

```
bmi_list = []
...
bmi = weight / height**2
bmi_list.append(bmi)
...
while ...:
    ....
    bmi = weight / height**2
    bmi_list.append(bmi)
    ...
...
print(sum(bmi_list))
```

### Note

There is also an error with `bmirange()`: `print()` is called twice.  You can either put the `print()` inside `bmirange()`, or you can `print()` the results of `bmirange()`, but doing both will result in `None` being printed out, which I assume is not what you want.

#### Solution 1

```
def bmirange():
    if bmi >= 25.0:
        print('Your BMI measurement shows that you are overweight')
    elif bmi <18.0:
        print('Your BMI measurement shows that you are underweight')
    else:
        print('Your BMI measurement shows that you are in the healty weight band')

...

bmirange() # will print itself
```

#### Solution 2

```
def bmirange():
    if bmi >= 25.0:
        return 'Your BMI measurement shows that you are overweight'
    elif bmi <18.0:
        return 'Your BMI measurement shows that you are underweight'
    else:
        return 'Your BMI measurement shows that you are in the healty weight band'

...

print(bmirange()) # will not print itself
```

Comment: Thankyou :) How can i add to your reputation? or something

Comment: @hennessyd: You can mark an answer as "accepted" by clicking on the check mark next to it, if that answer answered your question.

Comment: hi, im trying to now get a mean of the bmi's,   i've got, bmicount = 0...                                             weight / height**2
bmi_list.append(bmi)
bmicount +=1
while ...:
    ....
    bmi = weight / height**2
    bmi_list.append(bmi)                                      bmicount+=1                                                     ... else                                                           print(sum(bmi_list))
    print(sum(bmi_list))/(bmicount)                                       any ideas?

Comment: You have to put the division inside the `print()`.  You can get the length of a list with `len()`, so `print(sum(bmi_list) / len(bmi_list))` will print an average.